# Flask Authentication When Logging into External Applications

Tags: authentication, flask, jwt, mindsdb

I am currently in the process of creating a Flask API that interacts with MindsDB cloud. I am using MindsDB in the context of my application, however, my question really revolves around authenticating multiple users to any external application.

Now, in order to use my API, you need to have a cloud account created in MindsDB. The first step would be to authenticate the user. When using the MindsDB Python SDK, this is simply done as follows,

```
import mindsdb_sdk
server = mindsdb_sdk.connect(login='a@b.com', password='-')
```

I am thinking that the login route of my API would look something like this,

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    login = data.get('login')
    password = data.get('password')
    
    try:
        server = mindsdb_sdk.connect(login=login, password=password)
    except HTTPError as e:
        return jsonify(message=f'Authentication failed: {e}'), 401
```

However, the difference here to the usual APIs I have worked with (and their authentication mechanisms) is that I need the `server` object that is created above in my other routes.

This is what my typical authentication process would look like to handle multiple users with JWT,

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=data['username']).first()
    if user and user.password == data['password']:
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)
        return jsonify(message='Login successful', access_token=access_token)
    return jsonify(message='Invalid credentials'), 401

@app.route('/protected', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    return jsonify(message='Protected route. Authentication successful!')
```

I also understand the use of `additional_claims` to pass data on through the JWT token as shown here,

```
create_access_token(identity=user.id, additional_claims={"email": user.email})
```

It is obviously not a good idea for me to pass the password on to other routes this way due to security concerns.

How can I pass my object along? In a secure and reliable way? It should also scale to multiple users.